# Update SVN under my Mac OSX 10.5

Tags: svn, macos

I had downloaded and installed the 1.6.9 version of SVN from http://subversion.tigris.org/.
After the installation I noticed that if I launch the command "svn" from the terminal, my Mac still uses the old version, the 1.4.4.
If i want to use the new version, I need to specify its path, like this:
- /opt/subversion/bin/svn commit
instead of:
- svn commit

There is a way to solve this problem and use the new version of the command without typing the entire path?

Tanks

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - just add `/opt/subversion/bin` to your `PATH`.

For example, put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="/opt/subversion/bin/:$PATH"
```

(and if that doesn't work, try putting it in `~/.bash_profile` - I never remember which one works for OS X).

Oh, and you'll need to open a new terminal for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, i have created the ~/.bash_profile file and it's works!